# How to use same control inside that control in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-template

I have used my slitter control inside splitter. I have tried like below it won't work.

In the below sample, I have rendered splitter control inside the splitter

> sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndqigp-hnwt7c?file=code-editor-layout.html

But I have found the solution if I tried using ng-container it is working fine. refer below

> Sample with **ng-container** - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndqigp-dy6dei?file=code-editor-layout.html

And also, I can able to achieve my scenario like below:

I have initialized splitter as a component, then I used it is working

> Sample -https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndqigp-ixe646?file=code-editor-layout.html

Please suggest which one is best way and why my first sample not working?